# Kibana shows logs after 5 minutes kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, fluentd, efk

I'm using EFK setup, have a problem with showing logs in Kibana.
Kibana shows log after 5 minutes in Elasticsearch and kibana.
My Fluentd config-

fileConfigs:
02_apps.conf: |

```
  <filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.**>
    @type record_transformer
    <record>
      log_json ${record["log"]}
    </record>
  </filter>

  <filter kubernetes.var.log.containers.**>
    @type parser
    @log_level debug
    key_name log_json
    reserve_data true
    remove_key_name_field true
    emit_invalid_record_to_error false
    <parse>
      @type json
    </parse>
  </filter>    
  
  <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**>
    @type elasticsearch
    @log_level debug
    suppress_type_name true
    host "es-logging-perf-lb"
    port 80
    reload_connections false
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix ${$.kubernetes.labels.app}
    reconnect_on_error true
    reload_on_failure true
    reload_connections false
    request_timeout 2147483648
    num_threads 4
    <buffer tag, $.kubernetes.labels.app>
       @type file
       path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes-test.system.buffer
       flush_mode interval
       retry_type exponential_backoff
       flush_thread_count 4
       flush_interval 5s
       #timekey_wait 0s
       retry_forever true
       retry_max_interval 30
       chunk_limit_size 50M
       queue_limit_length 32
       overflow_action block
    </buffer>
  </match>
```

My Setup Fluentd > Elastisearch and handling 300 tps transaction.
ES- data-nodes (5) > 8 core CPU and 32 Memory

ES- Master and ingestion-nodes > 4 core CPU and 16 Memory
Please share your suggestion and inputs.

Comment: Have you tried changing `flush_intervel`? Does it make any changes at all? How is ES's performance? Have you checked `fleuntd` logs? do you see any warnings/errors etc. Debug logs may help as well.

Comment: Yes I changed flush_intervel to 3s but couldn't get success. ye there is warning and debug logs

Comment: [info]: #0 stats - namespace_cache_size: 3, pod_cache_size: 414, pod_cache_watch_delete_ignored: 2, pod_cache_watch_updates: 1062, pod_cache_watch_misses: 9, pod_cache_watch_ignored: 1, namespace_cache_api_updates: 36, pod_cache_api_updates: 36, id_cache_miss: 36, pod_cache_host_updates: 414, pod_watch_gone_errors: 1, pod_watch_gone_notices: 1
2022-01-21 09:59:46 +0530 [debug]: #0 Created new chunk chunk_id="5d610119c740431db79e8db7876d36a0" metadata=#<struct Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::Metadata timekey=nil, tag="kubernetes.var.log.containers.XXXX-78cb56f5b7-kvl7v_XXXX.log", variables=nil, seq=0>

Comment: 2022-01-21 10:44:22 +0530 [info]: #0 stats - namespace_cache_size: 3, pod_cache_size: 416, pod_cache_watch_delete_ignored: 16, pod_cache_watch_updates: 1251, pod_cache_watch_misses: 89, pod_cache_watch_ignored: 11, namespace_cache_api_updates: 64, pod_cache_api_updates: 64, id_cache_miss: 64, pod_cache_host_updates: 414, pod_watch_gone_errors: 1, pod_watch_gone_notices: 1

Comment: 2022-01-21 10:45:24 +0530 [info]: 410 Gone encountered. Restarting pod watch to reset resource versions.410 Gone

Comment: HI @Anup, There are no errors in the logs just `info`. The issue seems to be with ES plugin. Are you running an updated version of fluentd? Can you also change `flush_mode interval` to `flush_mode immediate`?